# Struggling with Xcode 4

Tags: frameworks, xcode4, linker

I've recently downloaded Xcode 4 and now two of my projects that were working perfectly fine before have started giving me errors. Both errors are effectively to do with linking options, but I can't figure out how to change these options and get rid of the errors.

The first problem is with a project written in C++ using the SDL_ttf and SDL_image frameworks. The project builds correctly, but when I try to run, it gives me the following warnings on the console:

> > warning: Unable to read symbols for @executable_path/../Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL_ttf (file not found).
> >     warning: Unable to read symbols from "SDL_ttf" (not yet mapped into memory).
> >     warning: Unable to read symbols for @executable_path/../Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/Versions/A/SDL_image (file not found).
> >     warning: Unable to read symbols from "SDL_image" (not yet mapped into memory).

Since the files are not being found, the executable cannot load any images making it exit straight away when I try to load images. I think the issue here is that the frameworks are not in the directory above the executable, they are in `/Library/Framework/` which worked fine before in Xcode 3.2. How do I resolve this?

The second problem comes when compiling an application I wrote for iOS. Along with giving me a bunch of warnings about depracated code on iOS 5, which I will deal with later, it fails to build due to a linker error which I have no clue how to resolve, it says:

> > ld: library not found for -lz.1.2.3
> >     Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer the second question.

```
-lz.1.2.3
```

should be

```
-lz
```

You might have accidentally added the zlib.1.2.3.dylib to the project's "link binary with libraries" build phase. You should use the standard zlib without any version in its filename, or simply add -lz to the Other Linker Flags under Build Settings and not add zlib in the "link binary with libraries" build phase.

As for the missing frameworks my best guess is that it has to do with the relative path, ie if you can get rid of the /../ part and instead provide an absolute path that might resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks!! what you told me to do solved the second problem perfectly!

Comment: About the first problem, yeah thats exactly what i think i need to do, i just don't know how to change that, i don't know where the option is for changing the paths. In build settings both the Framework and Header search paths are the absolute paths, i don't know where else in my projects it might be set to search by the relative paths, if i knew that i might be able to fix it, any ideas?

Comment: Regarding your first problem, I had exactly the same thing happen to me. I don't know why this solved it, but instead of having SDL_ttf.framework in /Library/Frameworks to /Users/eml/Library/Frameworks (your-home-folder/Library/Frameworks).

Comment: Yeah Thanks eml i did that just a few minutes ago b4 checking back here and that solved the problem, i just have the framework now in both ~/Library/Framework and /Library/Framework... Thanks both of you, i have now resolved both problems!